# Mysterious error in CREATE PROCEDURE in MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I tried to make a simple procedure in MariaDB 10.2 but I encountered an issue regarding variables defining.

I am receiving **(conn:107) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3** message when I declare a variable.

I read the MariaDB documentation and I it says that a variable is defined like this **DECLARE var_name [, var_name] ... type [DEFAULT value]**

Where I am wrong? I am coming from Oracle SQL and some sintax is wired for me.

I use Eclipse with MariaDB JDBC to connect on SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nom_jobs_insert(IN p_name varchar(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8')
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT count(*) INTO counter
    FROM nom_jobs
    WHERE lower(name) = lower(p_name)

    IF counter = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO nom_jobs(name) VALUES (p_name);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7cf721858e42e62dee14a3d173a6187c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

In MariaDB you have to define a **delimiter** before create a procedure and you need to mark where the procedure code is finished.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE nom_jobs_insert(IN p_name varchar(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8')
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT count(*) INTO counter
    FROM nom_jobs
    WHERE lower(name) = lower(p_name);

    IF counter = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO nom_jobs(name) VALUES (p_name);
    END IF;
END; //
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error not in `DECLARE` expression, add `;` after `SELECT` statement

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried in MySQL Workbench and it tell me at the '0' from declare statement that it missing semicolon even it's a semicolon after '0'...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the clues that point to a missing `DELIMITER`:

- `near '' at line 3`
- Line 3 contains the first `;`
- When the error says `near ''`, the parser thinks it has run off the end of the "statement".

Put those together -- it thinks that there is one 3-line statement ending with `;`.  But the `CREATE PROCEDURE` should be longer than that.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nom_jobs_insert(IN p_name varchar(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8')
IS
DECLARE counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    

    SELECT count(*) INTO counter
    FROM nom_jobs
    WHERE lower(name) = lower(p_name)

    IF counter = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO nom_jobs(name) VALUES (p_name);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It  shows another error: "...check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS'".