# MySQL - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax- phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am running below stored procedure in PhpMyAdmin:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ForgotPassword (
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    p_mobileNo VARCHAR(50),
    p_emailId VARCHAR(300),
    p_password VARCHAR(300),
    p_otp VARCHAR(50),
    p_appInstanceCode CHAR(36))
BEGIN   
    DECLARE v_IsOTPValid TINYINT DEFAULT  NULL;
    SET v_IsOTPValid = NULL;
    DECLARE v_userCode CHAR(36);

    IF (v_IsOTPValid = 1)
    THEN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM OTP WHERE otp = p_otp AND mobileNo = p_mobileNo)
        THEN

            SET v_userCode = (SELECT userCode FROM UserLogin WHERE userName = p_emailId);

            UPDATE UserLogin UL
            SET password = p_password 
            WHERE userName = p_emailId AND userCode = v_userCode;

            -- Delete the verified OTP 
            DELETE FROM OTP WHERE otp = p_otp AND mobileNo = p_mobileNo;

            DECLARE v_Token CHAR(36);


            INSERT INTO Token (createdAt, updatedAt,code,userCode,appInstanceCode,deviceIMEI,deviceName)
                                VALUES (NOW(),NOW(),v_Token,v_userCode,p_appInstanceCode,NULL,NULL);


            SELECT 200 code, 'Password changed succesfully' as message,v_Token;
        ELSE
            SELECT 400 as code, 'Invalid OTP or Mobile No' as message,v_Token;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        SELECT 401 as code, 'OTP expired' as message,v_Token;
    END IF; 
END
//
delimiter ;
```

But it keep showing me an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v_IsOTPValid TINYINT DEFAULT  NULL;
>       SET v_IsOTPValid = NULL;
>       DECL' at line 9

I tried:

[Is declare in mysql giving syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732625/is-declare-in-mysql-giving-syntax-error)

and

[Mystery error in CREATE PROCEDURE in MariaDB/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062973/mystery-error-in-create-procedure-in-mariadb-mysql)

But none of those answers help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have  a SET before the end of all DECLARE  statements..

and as per [`official documentation`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare.html), place all the declare before the set or any other statement:

```
BEGIN   
  DECLARE v_IsOTPValid TINYINT DEFAULT  NULL;
  DECLARE v_userCode CHAR(36);
  DECLARE v_Token CHAR(36); 
  SET v_IsOTPValid = NULL;
```

Comment: Got another error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v_userCode CHAR(36);`

Comment: try move all the declare before the set

Comment: just s uggestion  looking to your code  ..  Setting the v_IsOTPValid  to null and fter check if is =1 seems non senso to me..

Comment: Yes there is a scalar function which will set the value for it but for now (for ques) I removed it

Comment: BTW thanks! I unable to find out any documentation about it even on the other similar questions no one pointed out this!

Comment: Can you add that line to the answer? About declaring variables? will help for future readers!

Comment: this type of sintax error are easy to discover because the possible causes are restrictec  to data type sintax or code position sintax ..

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to declare a display width for integer types, like `TINYINT(1)`. It has no effect on their size or the range of values they accept. See my answer to [Types in MySQL: BigInt(20) vs Int(20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20/3135854#3135854)

Comment: @BillKarwin  then also  the first error is related in this case to wrong  SET position  ??  ..ansawef  updated with your suggestion  ..  thanks

Comment: All the `DECLARE` statements need to be at the beginning of the `BEGIN` block, including `DECLARE v_Token CHAR(36)` which is currently on line 27.